# Refresh iOS widget when shown

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

I've created an iOS widget which has a time line policy that updates it every 5 minutes. However I would like to force the refresh of the widget when the user reaches the screen where it's being shown.

Is it possible to do that?

I know that it's possible to force the refresh of the widget from the app, but I want to force the refresh when it's shown to the user

Comment: You have no way to know when the widget is active on the user's screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorry there is no control for that inside the widget , It's update policy depends on many things like if the app is opened or not and last update time , your lower value time setting will make it's possibility higher to update but other things are managed by the IOS and we can't control them , there are many time sensitive apps that complains from that like alarms as IOS is always likes to save battery